# How we call "Pages" name in Dropdown in Signup form of PHPfox?

Tags: phpfox

In PHPfox, i want to call "Pages" name in drop-down in Signup form. Reason for calling "Pages", Actually i have created many pages for college name & that are saved in database. So if someone comes for signup, i want to show them college name in drop-down (which are basically "Pages").

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 plugins, one to show the HTML and one to process what to do with the user input:
1) Make a plugin that fetches the pages, maybe the hook `user.component_controller_register_1` or another in that controller would do but otherwise you can always use a low level hook like `run_start` and check if its the section where you want it.

To show the HTML you have 2 options: include a JS file to populate the sign up form with anything that you want, or if you have a custom template you can just assign the array to the template variable and look through it in your template.

2) Once the html part is showing and working make a plugin for the sign up routine, I think the hook user.service_process_add_1 should be enough given its location.

Dont forget that the input name for the signup is an array, so your drop down needs to look somewhat like this:

```
<select name="val[my_dropdown]">
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me in details. Actually i am beginner in PHPFox. In which page/module i will have to do this things?

Comment: I wrote an article about this http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/264/primer-on-hooks-plugins/

Comment: @Purefan Somehow The page is not found.. It gives  404 error. Want to read your article...

Comment: @user3419778 That link is over 1 year old, I suggest you search the new phpfox.com site for more info but I don't know if they kept the articles or if they are relevant with the new version